# Porting an iPhone game to Android - Textures and Buffers

Tags: c++, android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have programmed my game in C++. I have managed to compile everything using ndk, but I have notice a couple of snags.

How do I load textures into NDK OpenGL(since the code is already there)? I did use a BitmapFactory to load the image, then copy the pixels into a ByteBuffer which I allocated at a size of width * height * 4. I then sent the array of the ByteBuffer to my native code and pulled out a pointer using Get/ReleasePrimiativeArrayCritical. I don't think it works as it crashes when it renders. Also, I can't help but notice the Garbage Compiler is moaning about 5.37 MB of space being taking up when the image is only 16 KB.

The other thing is buffers, like framebuffers and renderbuffers. I notice that it isn't any use of framebuffers and renderbuffers. Does GLSurfaceView atuomatically do this? And is it okay to use my own buffers?

Comment: so you are keeping textures in arrays? (or tables) on cpu side?

Comment: urm... from iPhone I learnt to malloc(width * height * 4) for the image data. Then load the actual data into memory so I can load it on the using glTexImage2D. I am using ByteBuffer to do the same, just passing the reference over, getting the pointer and then loading up the image, glTexImage2D. I would then release them once in memory. So, no, I'm not keeping textures in arrays (or tables) on the cpu side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have figured it out. It turns out the BitmapFactory was scaling my images to a non power of 2 size so it would not work. GLSurfaceView supports the OpenGL ES 1.0 way of doing things, you just draw on-screen. I can use framebuffers, but to I have to link them to a texture and then draw the texture to screen. I used this [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FrameBufferObjectActivity.html) and ported it across to native excluding the depth buffer.

Here's the code:

Java:

```
public class NativeRenderer implements Renderer {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Test");
    }

    private static native void init();
    private static native void setTexture(byte[] data, int width, int height);
    private static native void resize(int width, int height);
    private static native void render();

    private Context mContext;

    public NativeRenderer(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        render();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        resize(width, height);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        init();

        ByteBuffer data;

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;  //ARGB_888 is the default
        opts.inDensity = 240; // this needed so my images are 512x512 (power of 2)
        opts.inScaled = false; // someone suggested to add this
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.image, opts);

        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        data = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4);

        Log.i(TAG, "allocate:" + (width * height * 4));
        data.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(data);
        data.position(0);
        bitmap.recycle();

        Log.i(TAG, "data.hasArray():" + data.hasArray());

        setTexture(data.array(), width, height);
    }
}
```

C++:

```
#include "your_company_NativeRenderer.h"
#include <android/log.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Functions.h"

static GLuint texture[2];
static GLuint framebuffer;
static GLuint renderbuffer;
static GLuint texturebuffer;
static int textureWidth;
static int textureHeight;
static int sWidth;
static int sHeight;
static float hheight;

void viewportFramebuffer()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    static float viewportFramebufferRight = 160.0f + (320.0 / (float)sWidth) * (textureWidth - sWidth);
    static float viewportFramebufferTop = hheight + ((2 * hheight) / (float)sHeight) * (textureHeight - sHeight);

    glOrthof(-160.0f, viewportFramebufferRight, -hheight, viewportFramebufferTop, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void viewportSurface()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, sWidth, sHeight);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrthof(-160.0f, 160.0f, -hheight, hheight, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_company_NativeRenderer_init
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "init()");

    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glGenTextures(2, texture);
    texturebuffer = texture[0];
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_company_NativeRenderer_setTexture
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jbyteArray array, jint width, jint height)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "setTexture()");

    void *image = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(array, 0);
    unsigned int *imageData = static_cast<unsigned int *>(image);

    flipImageVertically(imageData, width, height); // flips the bytes vertically

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(array, image, 0);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_company_NativeRenderer_resize
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint width, jint height)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "resize(width:%d, height:%d)", width, height);

    sWidth = width;
    sHeight = height;

    hheight = 240.0f + additionToScalePlane(width, height); // used to adjust the spect ratio
    // iPhone is 2 : 3, my Galaxy S is 5 : 3

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "hheight:%g", hheight);

    textureWidth = powerOf2Bigger(width);
    textureHeight = powerOf2Bigger(height);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "texture:{w:%d, h:%d}", textureWidth, textureHeight);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturebuffer);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glColor4ub(0, 0, 0, 255);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    int area[] = {0.0, 0.0, sWidth, sHeight}; // using draw_texture extension

    glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, area);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturebuffer, 0);

    int status = glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES);
    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "Framebuffer is not complete: %x", status);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_company_NativeRenderer_render
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
    static float texCoord[] = {
            0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 480.0/512.0,
            320.0/512.0, 0.0,
            320.0/512.0, 480.0/512.0,
    };

    static float vertex[] = {
            -160.0, -240.0,
            -160.0, 240.0,
            160.0, -240.0,
            160.0, 240.0,
    };

    //off-screen
    viewportFramebuffer();

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);

    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertex);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoord);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 0);

    //on-screen
    viewportSurface();

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*static float textureCoord[] = {
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, sHeight/(float)textureHeight,
        sWidth/(float)textureWidth, 0.0,
        sWidth/(float)textureWidth, sHeight/(float)textureHeight,
    };

    static float textureVertex[] = {
            -160.0, -hheight,
            -160.0, hheight,
            160.0, -hheight,
            160.0, hheight,
    };*/ //if there isn't draw_texture extension

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturebuffer);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, sWidth, sHeight);

    //glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureVertex);
    //glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureCoord);
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    //glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    //glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```